# How can I remove the bottom border in the react-bootstrap navbar component?

Tags: css, reactjs, bootstrap-4

so I'm working on a project using reactjs(not native) and I'm having a css issue with react-bootstrap. When using the Navbar component with inverse and fluid styling to it I'm getting a small bottom border. It's not only for that as, it's when I'm using the PageHeader component as well. I've tried various css changes to .navbar/.navbar-header/.navbar-default like "border-bottom: none !important;" "border-radius: 0;" and none have succeeded. I can edit other things such as the background color though.. Thanks

Navigation.js (this section of code shows navbar options for an authenticated user)

```
const NavigationAuth = () =>
<div>
    <Navbar inverse fluid>
        <Navbar.Header>
            <Navbar.Brand>
                <a href="/"> Bug Tracker </a>
            </Navbar.Brand>
        </Navbar.Header>
        <Nav pullRight>
            <NavItem eventKey={1} href={routes.LANDING}>Landing</NavItem>
            <NavItem eventKey={2} href={routes.HOME}>Home</NavItem>
            <NavItem eventKey={3} href={routes.ACCOUNT}>Account</NavItem>
            <NavItem>
                <SignOutButton />
            </NavItem>
        </Nav>
    </Navbar>
</div>
```

App.js (Where the navigation component is called) (code snippet of class App)

```
render() {
return (
  <Router>
    <div>
      <header>
        <Navigation />
        <hr />
        <Route
          exact path={routes.LANDING}
          component={() => <LandingPage />}
        />
```

App.css (navbar css attempt snippet)

```
.navbar-header {
   border-bottom: none;
}
```

Comment: can you add some code

Comment: @RajatDhoot just added a couple snippets of where it is used. And those components are imported from 'react-bootstrap'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your border is coming from your `Navbar` component  which has a `.navbar.navbar-default` class...so you will need to remove border from that class

```
.navbar.navbar-default {
  border-bottom: 0;
}
```

Comment: @namesjj well it should work...try to give a custom class of yours in navbar and then use it like `.custom-class.navbar.navbar-default`....

Comment: Still can't resolve the navbar bottom border, but for the PageHeader component I made an inline style variable with borderBottome: 'none' and that worked. Not sure why the navbar isn't taking the css change though

Comment: @namesjj try to inspect in the browser that your css is coming or not...

Comment: I did not know how powerful the inspect elements tool is!! I found the issue, it was the <hr> tag below <Navigation /> in my App.js Can't believe I overlooked that.. Thank you

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
className="border-0"
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).